# Apache Tika Office to PDF conversion

Tags: apache-tika

I am trying to convert office files to PDF using POI and iText. I am able to do the basic conversion where I read the word file using WordExtractor and write the contents to PDF file using PDF writer.

However, this does not retain the structure (tables, styles etc). I have come across this forum that you can retain the formats using Tika. Are there any working examples for this?

Comment: An example of using Tika? Or of taking the HTML it produces (complete with styles, tables etc) and turning that into a PDF with iText?

Comment: I already am working on Tika and have enough understanding of the same. However I am looking for something to convert office files to PDF while retaining the tables, styles, colors etc - basically the entire structure of the document.

Comment: An intern, a copy of microsoft office and the export to PDF button? Or does it need to be automated, and if so, for what platform?

Comment: Did you get to know how to do it....